# I want to get The Spinner Id from the below code not the text

Tags: android

This is my code.

```
public class EmployeeProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinnerbranches;

    ArrayList<String> branchnames;

    JSONArray branches=new JSONArray();

    Integer branchid=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_profile);

        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new 
        ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f43f10"));
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        spinnerbranches = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.EmpbranchesSpinner);
      getBrach();
    }

      private void getBrach(){
        // Spinner spinnerbranches;
        // ArrayList<String> branchnames;
        // JSONArray branches;
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"http://zamzamapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Branches",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {



                            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response);

                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            branches = j.getJSONArray("DDL");

                            //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                            getBranchs(branches);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void getBranchs(JSONArray jsonArray){
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        branchnames=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                branchnames.add(json.getString("name"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        spinnerbranches.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(EmployeeProfile.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, branchnames));
       // spinnerbranches.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(branch));
        spinnerbranches.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>) spinnerbranches.getAdapter()).getPosition(branch));
        spinnerbranches.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                branchid = (int) id + 1;


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This is my Json Array

```
{"DDL":[{"Id":1,"name":"ZamZam Managers1"},{"Id":3,"name":"ZamZam Managers2"},{"Id":4,"name":"ZamZam Chefs1"},{"Id":7,"name":"ZamZam Chefs2"},{"Id":8,"name":"ZamZam Waiting staff1"},{"Id":10,"name":"ZamZam Waiting staff2"},{"Id":11,"name":"ZamZam Accountant1"}]}
```

Comment: Can you please give more information what exactly you want from the above code?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: i want to get the selected item's id for the future use...Are you clear..?

Comment: APIResponse apiResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response, APIResponse.class);
                        salaryList.clear();
                        // salaryList.addAll(apiResponse.getIndevSalary());
                        salaryList.addAll(apiResponse.getExtraWork());

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code  help you

if your want to select id then

```
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           try {
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Json_Data opt_code = new Json_Data();
                opt_code.setName(jsonobject.optString("name"));
                opt_code.setId(jsonobject.optString("ID"));
                json_data.add(opt_code);
                datalist.add(jsonobject.optString("ID"));

                }
              }
               catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks... here im getting the selected item text but i need the id of selected item

Comment: hey add a new arraylist for id then you can select id [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34065137/4824159)

Comment: great help, it helps me alot

Answer (score 1):

You required Item Id Right ? means If you click on 'ZamZam Chefs1' you need id = 4 Right . . ?

```
 {
  "Id": 4,
  "name": "ZamZam Chefs1"
}
```

If you required same thing ? Then you can do one thing, when ever 'onItemSelected' you can do

```
        String name = branchnames.get(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (obj.optString("name").equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            requiredID = obj.optInt("name");
            break;
        }
    }
```

this is one way. Another one when you are making 'branchnames' String array list parallel you need to make another id's array and get that item with position in  'onItemSelected' of your spinner.

Comment: Thanks for answaering,,,but im getting error when item selecting.. i selected ZamZam Accountant1  ..."java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 4"